# How can I change my equation?

Tags: c, equation

I need to have the user input a 1 or 0 for taxable or not.  could someone help because when the user inputs 0 it makes the out put 0.  Here is my code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAX_RATE 0.065

int main() {
  int item_value;
  int total_items;
  double total_cost;
  double is_taxable;

  printf("What is the cost of the item to be purchased (in dollars)?\n");
  scanf("%d", &item_value);

  printf("How many of the items are you purchasing?\n");
  scanf("%d", &total_items);

  printf("Is the item taxed (1 = yes, 0 = no)?\n");
  scanf("%lf", &is_taxable);

  total_cost =(TAX_RATE+is_taxable)*(item_value*total_items); 

  printf("Your total cost is %.2lf.\n", total_cost);

  system("Pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what you expect vs what you are getting.

Comment: Can you provide some example input and output?

Comment: Change `(TAX_RATE+is_taxable)` to `(TAX_RATE*is_taxable + 1.0)`.

Comment: Thank you chux and I am not allowed to use an if or switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

to keep the code simple:

```
int is_taxable;
...
scanf("%d", &is_taxable);
...

if (is_taxable)
  total_cost = (1 + TAX_RATE) * (item_value * total_items);
else
  total_cost = item_value*total_items;
```

*edit* I was not aware you could not use **if** (why ?). The change required is simply (remove the if/else)

```
total_cost = (1 + TAX_RATE * is_taxable) * (item_value * total_items);
```

Comment: `is_taxable` is of type `double`

Comment: @APerson: really it's a boolean, I changed type to int as seems more appropriate

Comment: Didn't see `int is_taxable;`, sorry

Comment: Im not allowed to use an IF or SWITCH, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of introducing a new variable "is_taxable" as suggested by CapelliC, you could do it the following way too.

```
total_cost =( 1 + TAX_RATE*is_taxable)*(item_value*total_items);
```

**Sample Output (with tax)**

```
What is the cost of the item to be purchased (in dollars)?
10
How many of the items are you purchasing?
2
Is the item taxed (1 = yes, 0 = no)?
1
Your total cost is 21.30.
```

**Sample Output (without tax)**

```
What is the cost of the item to be purchased (in dollars)?
10
How many of the items are you purchasing?
2
Is the item taxed (1 = yes, 0 = no)?
0
Your total cost is 20.00.
```

And to add few more suggestions, it would be better if you declared the type of "item_value" to be double so that user can enter input like 10.25. Else you will get erroneous results.

**Sample output (when 10.25 is entered as price)**

```
#./a.out
What is the cost of the item to be purchased (in dollars)?
10.25
How many of the items are you purchasing?
Is the item taxed (1 = yes, 0 = no)?
Your total cost is 332994.64.
```